# I cant convert number to string? (even when following what I've done before) [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, loops

I've heard a lot that the best way to learn to program is to experiment and test a bit. So I recently learned about loops and while loops etc. and decided to try and make a program that would just count from 0-100. I did this very easily, and everything works fine. The only thing not working is that fact that I can't get the value of count (ie 0,10,20, etc) to work in the console.log? Thanks so much.

```
for(var count=0; count<=100; count+=10)
{
    console.log("thrusters at "+count" percent!");
};
```

Comment: You're missing a `+` after your count variable

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a second +

```
for(var count=0; count<=100; count+=10)
{
    console.log("thrusters at " + count + " percent!");
};
```